# 401 error for downloading drive item contents

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I am getting the `HTTP 401` error for the file download URL generated by [`GET /users/{userId}/drive/items/{item-id}/content`](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/driveitem_get_content), which claims it doesn't require the authentication information.

This seems to happen if the prior request for file item information received `401` error and we refreshed the token, but not sure. Anyway, this always happens anyway from one of my customers' site, not happening frequently though.

Most of all, I'd like to know what's the best approach for the critical fix for my customer, and what's the real cause and solution.

Thanks.

Comment: You need to make sure you're calling `/content` with a valid token. Also keep in mind that this link only lives for a few minutes. After they're used/expired, the URL will return a `401`

Comment: Let's say I got the download URL for a file, and it's 30GB in size. If I do the partial download chunk by chunk which may take an hour to download the whole, then this kind of error can happen somewhere in the 'chunk download' loop?

Comment: I believe as long as you're specifying a `Range` header (`Range: bytes=0-1023`) it will keep the URL alive until you get an `HTTP 200` that signifies the download is complete (each chunk will be returned with an `HTTP 206 Partial Content`).

Comment: Yes I expected so, because I have tested with such large files and there was no problem. Only some shows this kind of error. 

Ok then (regardless the reason)  if I add 'bearer' header to the request, will it help ?

Comment: Not with the `DownloadUrl`, no. In fact, including it can result in a `403` because you end up with duplicate auth headers. You do need to make sure your token is fresh before you call `/content` however since that token expiring could result in a `401`. In other words, I'm leaning towards a race condition where you token expires before the download beings.

Comment: hmm... Ok Thanks Marc, I will check more about the race condition. It will take some time for me to test and will let you know if I come up with any answer.

Comment: Marc, regarding that 'race condition', I get the download URL properly by refreshing the token, and right after that I try the download. within that very short period, less than a second, could such 'race-condition' happen? Download started because I got the proper result with fresh token.

Comment: No, that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Hi, sorry to keep buggin you on this. I was thinking that 'race-condition' means the 'throttling limit' condition, but it seems you mean different one. Can you please be more explicit about it?

Comment: A race condition where an action is dependent on a specific execution order or must complete within a certain window of time. It becomes a problem when things do not happen in the correct order or a timeout occurs before it can complete. Tokens are a race condition because they have a limited lifetime. If you attempt to execute an action and your token expires before it completed, you've hit a race exception.

Comment: Created a new Azure app for the customer and tried simple user list discovery, and did batch request for their OneDrive quota information. And even for this request it returned 429 errors. It seems it's the environment issue (Australia) so I asked the customer to create ticket.